# Execute function from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to execute function from directive?

Or other variants to do this better.

Page:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click=refresh()></button>
    <bs-table ???></bs-table>
</div>
```

Main controller:

```
angular.module('app', ['bsTable'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.refresh = function() {
            ???
        };
}]);
```

Function added in directive's controller:

```
angular.module('bsTable', [])
    .directive('bsTable', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<table></table>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                ???
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element) {
                $element.bootstrapTable();
            },                
            controller: function ($scope, $element) {
                $scope.refresh = function() {
                    $element.bootstrapTable('refresh');
                };
            }                
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Which function do you want to execute? The refresh on the main ctrl?

Comment: Directive with isolate scope contains function refresh. Need execute refresh from main controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main controller:

```
$scope.functionToPass = function(anyParameter){ ... };
```

In directive:

```
...,
scope: {yourFunction:'=yourFunction'},
...,
```

In HTML:

```
<bs-table yourFunction="functionToPass">
```

Now you can access the function in the directive's controller and link as `$scope.yourFunction`.